# If I earn trading cards on steam when level 10 do I have to craft badges for xp or just get the cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

So I'm just wondering since I'm level 10 on steam and got 3 trading cards and haven't gotten any XP from it.

- Do I have to craft a badge?
- Before I was level 10 cards gave me XP, why don't they give me XP anymore?
- How much XP will I get from crafting a badge and leveling that badge up?

Well if any of you can answer back that would be great. Good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to craft a badge?

Yes, you have to craft a badge.

> Before I was level 10 cards gave me XP, why don't they give me XP anymore?

You never get XP from only cards, you get XP from crafting badges and buying games (2-3 xp per game) and some special badges such as "X+ games owned" or "member for Y years".

> How much XP will I get from crafting a badge and leveling that badge up?

100XP, for initial crafting and each leveling up.

You can level up normal badges until it reaches level 5, but foil ones have only one level. Foil badges give 100XP too.

The amount of badges required per level is `floor(level/10)+1`, so lets say that you are level 15, it is `floor(1.5)+1` -> `1+1` -> `2` because the amount of XP required to level up increases by 100xp on every 10 levels.

Comment: @captaincj2005 if this answer helped you, please consider clicking the tick icon to accept this answer.